# absolute value equations with parameter

Tags: absolute-value

|2x - 3a| + |a + 1 - x| = |x + 1|

I am failing to compare (3/2)a and a+1 when searching for critical points. I am aware that this question was answered before but I couldn't understand it. 
How to find subintervals for x ?
Thanks!

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima can you help me more? Sorry for bothering

Comment: @kenobe Your equation it's just sadism!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg unprofessional ..

Comment: Begin by the case $a=2$. then $a>2 $ 3 for example and $a <2$ 1 for instance.

Comment: I did it. Since a>0 there are 8 cases (4+4) which give same solution : x=a and x=2a+1

Comment: @kenobe Why a is positive.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima I was very rude for not writing that condition. It was given in the task.